# Load dynamically a tree when page lods

Tags: extjs

I have a tree loaded when i click but i needed this tree to be loaded when page loads(at start).

Comment: Can you share a bit of the code in question?

Comment: We need sample code.  Essentially what you need to do is autoLoad your TreeNodes instead of on the click event.

Comment: i have a tree structure like this (raj,sachin,.....etc), in this i need a load only sachin ID when page loads automatically sachin contents should load.

Answer (score 0):

Supposing your tree ID is "13" (as mentionned in your code)

You should do :

```
Ext.onReady(function () {
    Ext.getCmp("15").load();
});
```

Comment: Ext.getCmp("13").getStore is not a function